# How to create a gentle summer breeze and gentle leafy breezes?

Tags: foley, wind

I’ve read about turning bikes upside down and all sorts but i’m just starting out and any simple but effective ways would be great!

Comment: Why didn't the bike trick work for you? Basically wind doesn't make any noise of its own, only when it passes over a surface... spinning bike wheels are a pretty simple way of making the surface move instead of the wind.

Comment: Hi Tetsujin, thanks for being the first reply! It’s only simply because i’m not able to use a bike so was hoping for any other household items. :)

Comment: You need something where the mechanical noise generated by the 'driver' is far below the noise floor of the sound you need from the wind. A bike is the most common 'household' item that can fill that brief, in a reasonably constant way, with variation provided by pedalling speed. A hand fan will make a small wind noise, but you can't keep it constant. a tube waved also, but you get a lot of doppler.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply! That’s given me a lot of food for thought. I understand more now why a bike is suggested, i just don’t think my parents would be happy with me bringing bikes in the house. I’ll see if i can find a hand fan in the mean time. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Let me try to point some of my comments more towards an answer...

If you really need the sound of wind, then you need to re-create the surfaces for it to interact with. Wind, by itself, doesn't actually make any noise.

An upturned bicycle is simply a convenient & common device whereby you can, rather than move the air, move a set of surfaces which will generate 'wind noise'. They rather conveniently have a pedal & gear structure so you can control the speed of the wheels & therefore the 'speed' or ferocity of the wind.

For a gentle ***leafy*** breeze, however, you may not actually need any real wind at all.
**[Packaging 'peanuts'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foam_peanut)** in a pillow-case or other soft-ish container can be gently shaken or stirred & can give a convincing 'rustle'. You can put them in a box, but you tend to get unwanted resonances from the box itself.